# Css - вертикальное выравнивание всей ссылки (блока целиком)

Tags: css

Подскажите пожалуйста новичку, что нужно сделать с css  что-бы выровнять центральный текст не меняя условия ссылки на целый блок?

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 200px 1fr 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.sidebar-left {
  background: red;  
}
.content{
  border: solid 1px;
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
 }
.sidebar-right {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="sidebar-left">
  </div>
    <a class="content" href="index.php">LKJHkljhlksjahf;ajshdf; kjhkhgjhgsjfhgaslfghaslkfdghlaskjfhglkasjhfglkasjhfglkajshfglkasjhgf ;jh;asjhdfklsajdhfk
  </a><div class="sidebar-right">ljh
  </div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8kxnr0qj/

Comment: Во-первых, переведите вопрос на русский язык (что вообще такое link conditions?), а во-вторых, `align-self: center` если я правильно понял вопрос

Comment: Спасибо, поправил. К сожалению align-self: center не помог, уменьшился блок. Хочу что бы весь блок был кликабелен.

Comment: Тогда нужно внутрь ссылки вложить ещё один блок и выровнять уже его

Comment: Спасибо, подскажите как будет выглядеть код?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так?

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 200px 1fr 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.sidebar-left {
  background: red;
}

.content {
  border: solid 1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  word-break: break-word;
}

.sidebar-right {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="sidebar-left">
  </div>
  <a class="content" href="index.php">LKJHkljhlksjahf;ajshdf; kjhkhgjhgsjfhgaslfghaslkfdghlaskjfhglkasjhfglkasjhfglkajshfglkasjhgf ;jh;asjhdfklsajdhfk
  </a>
  <div class="sidebar-right">ljh
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, супер!!!

Comment: Тогда, плиз, пометьте ответ как принятый.